# How do I add prerequisites to a ClickOnce application?

Tags: c#, winforms, deployment, clickonce

I want to add prerequisites to my Click Once application. Here is the problem. The program is in a server and clients install the application from the specific URL. I want to auto install the prerequisites (for example, Crystal Report Viewer) when the user first downloads and installs it, how could I do that?

I'm using C# Windows Forms and .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Are you saying you want crystal report viewer prerequisite to be shown in the list of prerequisites while creating the click once application? Which version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I w'd recommend you [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/prerequisites.html)

Comment: it may be anything. it may be another program. i just want to embed prerequisites to the system or give a specific path URL so it gets installed for the user.

Comment: @X-TECH: It's a commercial software

Comment: Yes you are right. Other options can be Wix, Install Shield limited Edition or Windows Installer in VS 2010

Comment: @LalindraKawshika: does my post answer your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a prerequisite first. The prerequisites that are shown in Visual Studio are in the following location

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages

You can create a Product Manifest through this [tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee335701.aspx)

Put it along with other bootstrapper packages.

Once this is done, you can select that prerequisite in your prerequisites window in publish settings and give the location from where you want the user to download it.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527233.aspx) is a complete tutorial for creating Localized Bootstrapper Package.

There is a tool called Bootstrap Manifest Generator. This [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15863/Add-your-own-custom-prerequisite-to-quot-ClickOnce) article is a complete tutorial for using this tool. I think this tool is not available from Microsoft directly any more.

Comment: What's the location for VS 15 community?I tried v10A isntead of v8.0A but it didn't show up on VS 15

Comment: I think this may be the location you want: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages..sorry for the late reply

Comment: This isnt later at all. I have asked a question about this here on VS and nobody has answered yet. I copied a EULAPackage from VS 13 packages (which was working fine) folder to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SDK\Bootstrapper\Packages` but it didn't show up on VS 15 pre-requisites. What am I missing?

Comment: I just tried copying an existing package. It didn't show immediately. But it shows after restarting. I hope you didn't miss out copying the package.xml file

Comment: I have both pakcage and product, in fact, I was using the files from this article: http://developers.de/blogs/bahro/archive/2015/09/01/add-eula-to-clickonce-installation-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Comment: I don't know why this wasn't working, but I just redownloaded the files (rather the use the same ones from my VS 13's package) and it worked for some reason. Thanks for your time Abhishek