# Create a program to install the prerequisites first?

Tags: c#, deployment, clickonce, prerequisites

Well here is the problem :) I have a system in c# .net framework 4.0 and program is stored in the server. Client access a web page and there is download button to install the system. But according to the client's requirements **I can't give them the .exe** file to download. only the Application Manifest file(click once file) is given. Prerequisites such as, 
**Windows Installer 4.5**
**Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)

Visual Basic Power Packs

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Report Viewer**
 
are given as links in the web page. So if the user gets an error he/she can download the necessary prerequisites file from the link. But they are confusing. What I want is create a another .exe program and when they click Download button in the web page first download the .exe file and install the prerequisites first and then forward the user to the web page and then download the click once. So no error occurs. If anyone have an idea way to create the mentioned prerequisites as a .exe file like installing one after the other give me an idea. Thanks a lot :)  If you don't understand the question please ask me :)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project's properties, then the **Publish** tab. Click the **Prerequisites** button and select what you need. If your prerequisites aren't listed [look at the answer to your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263636).

When you publish, it will generate a **setup.exe**. This bootstraps all your prerequisites together and launches your application after they are installed.