# Add Npcap as prerequisite for a ClickOnce installation

Tags: c#, clickonce, npcap

How to add an URL prerequisite for Npcap .exe installation via ClickOnce distributed application?

EDIT:

I went throught various tutorials, like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-create-a-package-manifest?view=vs-2019.

But nowhere were shown, on how to add an URL to point the User to the required installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add prerequisites to a ClickOnce application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263636/how-do-i-add-prerequisites-to-a-clickonce-application)

Comment: No. Firstly this post is very old and secondly I don't want to add an already built executable within the package. I just want to point to an URL, where the user can download it during the whole installation process.

Comment: Do you want to instruct the user to manually download the prerequisite (via displaying an URL) or the installer to automatically download it on its own?

Comment: I want to instruct the user to manually download the prerequisite.